# How to add space in react native application name?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

How can I add a space in my application name? Such as, if I do

```
react-native init HelloWorld
```

it would create an application with name HelloWorld. But if I do this

```
$ react-native init "Hello World"  
"Hello World" is not a valid name for a project.
Please use a valid identifier name (alphanumeric).
```

Is there any way to add space in the project name? I found a solution for iOS (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6115), but I'm developing for android. Please let me know how can I solve this problem.

Comment: Spaces or special characters are generally not advisable in situations like this because they will lead to unforeseen issues down the line, escaping characters etc. Can I ask why you need a space in the project name?

Comment: @brien.crean It seems the OP doesn't care about the project name, only the application name.  See the post the he refers to..it discusses changing the application name for ios.

Comment: @atlanteh ah I see, apologies I misread the question

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your projects in react-native can't have spaces in them, but you can change the app name directly in the android & ios projects.

**For android:**
go to android/app/src/main/res/values/string.xml and change app_name to your desired value.

**For ios:**
Go to ios/[currentName].xcodeproj/project.pbxproj and change the PRODUCT_NAME values, both in debug and release, from the current name to your new name.

or go to ios/[currentName]/info.plist, find this:

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
```

and replace the ${PRODUCT_NAME} with your desired name

Answer (score 10):

Add this key in info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key> 
<string>Top&#x2007;Articles</string>
```

Remember `&#x2007;` not worked in build setting of the project.`&#x2007;` this will work as space

```
Output:
Top Articles
```

Comment: This one actually works! Can't understand why it's underrated! Thank you mate!